# Laravel 5 Model Relation to Query in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

Schema **User** Table

```
ID|NAME
1 |John
2 |Doe
```

Schema **Financial** Table

```
ID|USER_ID|PROFIT |DATE
1 |1      |1000   |2016-12-22
2 |2      |-2000  |2016-12-22
3 |1      |2000   |2016-12-24
4 |2      |-2000  |2016-12-24
```

**User** Model

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function Financial()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Financial');
    }
}
```

**Financial** Model

```
class Financial extends Model
    {
        public function financial()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }
    }
```

**My Controller**

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user = User::get();
        $financial = Financial::get();
        return view('page.index',compact('user','financial'));
    }
}
```

**My Blade**

```
@foreach ($user as $u)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$u->id}}</td>
        <td>
             {{$u->financial->sum('gross')}}
             {{-- Above code doesn't work --}}
             {{-- Run something link --}}
             {{select (sum(profit) as total) from financial where user_id = $u->id}}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**QUESTION**

How can i achieve that **select** from my blade? i'm planning to use **@inject('DB','Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB')** so i can use **DB::raw** in my blade, but i'm confused on how to execute the query to achieve the **select** :(

Comment: You have a typo in your `transaction()` method in the `Financial::class`. You should also stick to Laravel conventions with naming and use a lower case `financials()` in the `User::class`. Another point is that you are using the wrong relation, it should be `hasMany('App\Financial')` in the `User::class`. Talking about naming convention, `transaction()` is probably not as good as `user()`, but this is your own choice.

Comment: Although it is possible, it is a bad idea to add application logic to the views. In case you'd change the views (template, layout, ...), you would also have to know about the application code, which can be cumbersome. Try to split your application into logic (controllers & services) and representation (views).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved by using [Laravel Collection Method ***Pluck***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers) and [Laravel Blade ***Service Injection***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers).Below is the code i've done to archive what i want:

```
@inject('financial','App\Financial') {{-- inject before foreach --}}
@foreach ($user as $u)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$u->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$financial->where('user_id','=',$u->id)->get()->pluck('profit')->sum()}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

To Evaluate what happen:

```
$financial->where('user_id','=',$u->id)->pluck('profit')->sum()
//   get financial where user_id = $u->id   // get the profit // sum the profit
```

**Cheers!**

Answer (score 3):

You could have simply done this:

```
{{$u->financial()->sum('gross')}}
```

If you are running a query on a relationship, add function brackets while calling it.

Comment: And I would also eager load the relation in the controller, using `with('financial')` and a closure, like `User::with('financial', function($q) { $q->sum('gross'); })->get();`. When doing so, the code above reduces to `{{ $u->financial }}`. Because you are accessing a already loaded relation, a function call is not necessary anymore.